# Nginx remove Secure Flag to Cookies from proxied server

Tags: security, nginx, https

I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy server. Is it possible to Remove the "secure" flag to the cookies somehow using Nginx? Modifying the path is possible so I guess it's also possible to modify cookie.

Comment: Did you find solution? I need to remove *Secure* flag also...

Answer (score 3):

An imperfect method:

```
proxy_cookie_path "~*^(.*?)$" $1\nX-User-Value:;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Here's how this works in case anyone is wondering: The directive matches any path using a regex, and the replacement keeps the path as-is, but causes everything following it to be moved into a new header named `X-User-Value`. The Secure will be discarded, as long as it is placed after the path in the original header.

Comment: You understand very thoroughly. It can only be used in the development environment, but not in the production environment !!!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite old question, but there is no answer here and I couldn't find fine solution for the same problem.

So I forked `nginx_cookie_flag_module` module and changed it to `nginx_unsecure_cookie_module`:
https://github.com/yumauri/nginx_unsecure_cookie_module

I'm frontend developer, my C/C++ knowledges are super low, but looks like it is working in my tests :) So I reckon it is good enough for development reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Since nginx 1.19.3 you can use http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_flags. For example:

```
proxy_cookie_flags some_cookie nosecure;
```

To remove the `Secure` flag from all cookies:

```
proxy_cookie_flags ~ nosecure;
```